# Having problem with fonts in vim-airline

Tags: fonts, vim, utf-8, vim-plugin

I wanted to install vim-airline but I am having problems with unicode fonts.

I have installed it with vundle:

**`.vimrc`**

```
set encoding=utf-8
Bundle 'bling/vim-airline'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme='powerlineish'
```

**`.fonts`**

```
$ ll .fonts
total 376
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 AnonymousPro
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 DejaVuSansMono
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 334548 gru 19 13:42 DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 DroidSansMono
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 Inconsolata
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 InconsolataDz
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 LiberationMono
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 Meslo
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:42 PowerlineSymbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx   1599 gru 19 13:26 README.rst
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 SourceCodePro
drwxr-xr-x 5 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 Terminus
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx xxx   4096 gru 19 13:26 UbuntuMono


fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts
/home/xxx/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 11 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/AnonymousPro: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/DejaVuSansMono: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/DroidSansMono: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Inconsolata: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/InconsolataDz: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/LiberationMono: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Meslo: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/PowerlineSymbols: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/SourceCodePro: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Terminus: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Terminus/BDF: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Terminus/PCF: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/Terminus/PSF: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/xxx/.fonts/UbuntuMono: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/home/xxx/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/home/xxx/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

Yet I still have those symbols

[image]

I have even tried inserting the symbols to `.vimrc`

```
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''
```

But they get inserted as such :

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution was to select the font that I have installed (the one with Powerline fixes) in Gnome terminal :

With the gnome-terminal active, click "Edit" > "Profile Preferences"

[image]

Now the fonts in tmux work fine.

Link to working fonts for powerline is here :

https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts

Comment: I did just that and still have the exact same problem. I followed the same path on the mac with iterm and selecting the font in iterm works perfectly but in gnome terminal I cannot see any change.

Comment: This IS the answer!